# Density of water after absorption

Tags: water, density

I was wondering if I could assume a water density ~1.0  g/cm3 after it was absorbed by the skin, or other medium.

I am particularly thinking on a molecular level, if the nanostructure and size of molecules of the absorbing medium can play a role in **keeping water molecules sufficiently isolated**.

At what point should I stop considering that clumps of a few water molecules can no longer be considered a liquid?

At what point does it stop to make sense to talk about density of water, or at what point should I start doubting that it's density is no longer the same as in liquid state?

Comment: Your quoted density only applies to pure water in bulk.  When you have a mixture or a very small number of water molecules, you haven't met these conditions.

Comment: Even in the opposite situation, where there's a small amount of other material absorbed by/dissolved in water, you can't say the density of the solution is the same. This is why you float more easily on the Dead Sea.

Comment: @DavidWhite it's exactly that I would to like to understand better. Until what point is such approximation valid

Comment: @probably_someone I am not talking about the density of the solution,only the water

Comment: @cinico, you must necessarily talk about solution density when other things are dissolved in water or water is dissolved in other things.  For real world applications, the point at which you have to consider such a solution will depend on some type of purity specification, so such a point varies depending on the application.

Comment: @DavidWhite but if it's not a solution, like the skin (or other solid) absorbing water? What should I consider? Is it the fact that there are "enough" number of molecules together to make clumps of liquid water?

Comment: @cinico, there are various types of solutions: solids dissolved in liquids, liquids dissolved in liquids, etc.  Also, the water normally doesn't "clump" together.  How much it wets a solid depends on how hydrophobic the solid is.  Your question is so very "open ended" that a definite answer can't be given.

Comment: @DavidWhite I'll add an example of the problem I was working that led me to this question. It might give a better insight of what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: It sounds like you just weigh the solid before adding water, then the difference is water after, which you can get he concentration from

Comment: @user47014 I didn't weight the solid

Comment: If you know the mass fraction, then you can weigh and measure the whole thing with the water and then get the concentration of water

Comment: @user47014 the thing in question cannot be weighted

Comment: So it sounds like a question of if the density of water changes at its contact point with a surface, and how far into the water that change is felt. so then the next question would be how much surface is it in contact with (i.e. how porous is the absorbing material). Wolgang Pauli (of the Pauli exclusion principle) once said, "God made the bulk; surfaces were invented by the devil". There is a lot of new research into surface science, with better ways to measure small things. I'm not aware of such research into water density at surfaces.